# What is the objective of model.matrix()?

Tags: r, regression, model.matrix

I'm currently going through the 'Introduction to Statistical Learning' MOOC by Stanford OpenX. In one of the lab exercises, it suggests creating a model matrix from the test data by explicitly using `model.matrix()`.

*Extract from textbook*

> We now compute the validation set error for the best model of each model size. We first make a model matrix from the test data.

```
test.mat=model.matrix (Salary∼.,data=Hitters [test ,])
```

> The model.matrix() function is used in many regression packages for
>   building an `X` matrix from data. Now we run a loop, and for each size `i`, we 
>   extract the coefficients from `regfit.best` for the best model of that
>   size, multiply them into the appropriate columns of the test model
>   matrix to form the predictions, and compute the test MSE.

```
val.errors =rep(NA ,19)
for(i in 1:19){
  coefi=coef(regfit .best ,id=i)
  pred=test.mat [,names(coefi)]%*% coefi
  val.errors [i]= mean(( Hitters$Salary[test]-pred)^2)
  }
```

I understand that `model.matrix` would convert string variables into values with different levels, and that models like `lm()` would do the conversions under the hood.

However, what are the instances that we would explicitly use `model.matrix()`, and why?

Comment: It is how linear algebra works. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix

Comment: You would do this if you need a design matrix. One of the reasons might be that you're using a procedure that needs this as input, i.e., you might be trying to implement some statistical method yourself (because it hasn't been implemented yet or to better understand another implementation). Or possibly you might want to use `lm.fit` for faster fitting, which needs a design matrix as input.